# Where can I find the radio program of יחוה דעת?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, hacham-ovadia-yosef

The books called יחוה דעת were authored by Rabbi Ovadya Yosef. In the title page, it states that these books are essentially transcriptions of a radio show called פניני הלכה, with small additions.  Are these radio shows available for listening? I’ve been unsuccessful in finding them thus far.
Evidence of a radio show is found in the [book of his predecessor Rav Nissim](https://www.sefaria.org/LaKelal_VeLaPerat%2C_Volume_I%2C_5_The_Status_of_Women.4.7?vhe=LaKelal_VeLaPerat,_Halakhot_Ketzuvot,_Jerusalem,_2017-2019&lang=he&with=all&lang2=he). It is dated 1971, two years before Rav Yosef assumed that position. It is unclear if this is the show of concern:

> אני שולח לכב' רשימה שפרסמתי בעתון בלדינו "לה־בירדד" המופיע בתל־אביב **בקשר עם אסור שהוכרז ברדיו ע"י הרב הראשי בעירנו, רבי עובדיה יוסף, על המנהג הנהוג מזה מאות בשנים** בקהילות הספרדיות בבלקן, וביחוד בשלוניקי, שהנשים מחויבות לברך על הלולב בסוכות, מנהג שמוכרחים לבטלו, לפי דעת רבנים שונים.

Comment: I would totally go for that too! Great question!

Comment: I doubt they are, or even will become, available. If you haven't done so yet, you could try contacting [Kol Yisrael](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kol_Yisrael), who aired the radio programs, or the Israeli Chief Rabbinate, as he was the Sephardi Chief Rabbi at the time. It may also be worth baring in mind that these radio shows were broadcast on Israeli Radio in the 70s and 80s. It may take a lot of effort, on the technical side, making them available to the public (assuming usable recordings even exist).

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you. I haven’t really put much thought thus far into the practicality of this question. I had more assumed that it is already out there because of the significance, and it would just take the right person to view this posting. However, you comment may be very valid indeed.

Comment: Bonus points for demonstrating one of the pages in the book spoken in the original.

Comment: [Apparently](http://web.archive.org/web/20161119065253/http://www.iba.org.il/general/html/archive.html) archived Kol Yisrael programs could be bought in the past, but as Kol Yisrael closed down and its stations transferred to other broadcasting companies, I don't know if this is still possible.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, from what I gathered, the religious programs of Kol Yisrael, from what I've gathered, eventually moved to Kan (כאן 11). They eventually [re-started the Kabbalat Shabbat program](https://www.kan.org.il/radio/program.aspx?progId=1233&page=5) which decades ago featured the פינת ההלכה that had the q&a with Rav Ovadyah, though they have other programs now for such q&a. From what I've gathered from their site, it's possible to contact them for old shows, so that might be a lead; perhaps they have access to the archives of פינת ההלכה.

Comment: Moreshet Maran has [forums](https://forum.moreshet-maran.com/index.php?forums/) - it may be worth asking there as they seem to be the people who would know.

Comment: @PopularIsn'tRight thank you I have started a coherent dialogue over there

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/59185917#59185917

Answer (score 1):

The Shiurim from Rabbi Ovadia Yosef were from פינת ההלכה that were played on 'רשת א of רדיו קול ישראל. Although to the best of my knowledge I am not aware of all the Shiurim being available, you can obtain many Shiurim from Rabbi Ovadia Yosef on Halachic issues at this [link](https://moreshet-maran.com/ovadiayossef-categories/%d7%a9%d7%99%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%a8%d7%99%d7%9d-%d7%9c%d7%94%d7%90%d7%96%d7%a0%d7%94-%d7%9e%d7%9e%d7%a8%d7%9f-%d7%94%d7%a8%d7%91-%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%91%d7%93%d7%99%d7%94-%d7%99%d7%95%d7%a1%d7%a3/).